# Android Socket - second attempt fails with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: java, android, sockets

The following code is called once a second. It appears to work the first time but fails on subsequent calls with a java.netConnectException ETIMEDOUT.
The receiving device is a MicroChip WiFi module probably with only one port.

```
private void sendData() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = null;
                DataOutputStream dataOut = null;
                try {
                    if (socket == null) {
                        socket = new Socket("1.2.3.4", 2000);
                    }
                    dataOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    dataOut.writeUTF(dataString());
                    L.d("send");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                            L.d("Skt close");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (dataOut != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOut.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception in thread", e.getStackTrace() + "");
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: I'd say check if the receiving side is behaving as expected. At first glance this seems ok. Just that you should make sure the first call has ended before you start the second. How do you schedule this?

Comment: Two seconds is far too short for a connect timeout. The number of ports at the target is irrelevant, as you are only using one of them. Your code is incorrectly structured. Code that depends on the success of prior code in a `try` block must be inside that same `try` block. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: You won't achieve anything by including `n` number of tries, only one would also do the same effect, if done the proper structuring! And, you're closing the connection in the thread finally; so why do you expect that it'd write data again?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I have been a procedural programmer since CPM days and probably have not adapted to OOPs. What I am attempting to do is transmit a string of data from a tablet to a device (Microchip module) at second intervals. This is why I am repetitively calling the above routine. Could anyone suggest a better way to go?